# GET request based on UserName

Tags: java, android, rest, authentication, get

I am working on adding a user login to my android application to increase the security and also identify users. I have a login screen where the user selects their name from the dropdown list first. Their selection is then stored in a variable called `userName`.

I then have 6 boxes where the user enters in their unique pin, which is saved to a variable called `userPin`.

I have an oracle database table which has the username and pin for each of the employees and currently have a REST service which I am using to send data from my app to a different table in the same schema.

My question is... how can I first of all perform a GET request to get the userPin from my oracle database which is associated with the username that has been selected by the user?

Any help would be appreciated!

Code attempt:

```
  private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            String url = "http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx/engAppApi/webservices/userTable/Employee_Name=" + employee;

            URL object = new URL(url);

            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");

            if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                    userPinRetrieved+=line;
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("ErrorAPP", e.toString());
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: share your code and explain where you stuck and what is the error you getting

Comment: http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: @Thunder Code added

Answer (score 0):

Your Question Is Not That Clear, You Should Include

1. How You Are Calling Your REST Requests.
2. Any Effort You Have Done To Achieve This.
3. What Is The Error You Are Getting.

And for calling any **REST** request (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) you can use android libraries which will make your work very easy and efficient. Some mostly used libraries with examples are shown Below:-

1.[Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit)
 
I Am Not That Much Familiar With Retrofit So Here's A Link You Can Follow
 
[Tutorial For Retrofit](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-retrofit-2--cms-27792)

2.[Volley](https://github.com/google/volley)
Volley Is Developed By Google And Widely Used By Programmers For Developing Android Applications.

Example For Calling A GET request:-

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
}
```

Code Above Is For Adding Library To Your Project.

```
String url = "http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx/engAppApi/webservices/userTable/Employee_Name=" + employee;

 //creating a string request to send the request to the URL
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, JSON_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                //Printing Your Response To LOGCAT
                 Log.d("VolleyResponse","Response:- "+response);    
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                 //Printing Your Error Response To LOGCAT
                 Log.e("VolleyResponse","Error Response:- "+error.getMessage());
                }
            });

    //creating a request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //adding the string request to request queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

For More Information On Volley You Can Follow [This](https://androidclarified.wordpress.com/2017/07/15/android-volley-example/) Link.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment, I will update what I am trying to achieve

Comment: So above, I am trying to get the pin associated with whatever employee name is selected from the drop down menu?

Comment: Try The Edited Code Above, Make Sure To Replace Your URL and Adding The Dependencies and the INTERNET permission. @AndroidBeginner2018

Comment: will that retrieve the pin?

Comment: You better try that and check the logcat for response